# Jquery Masonry Layout gets disrupted on first load

Tags: jquery, html, gridview, jquery-masonry

I'm using the following grid layout jquery script in my blog
[Site](http://stenzil-demo.blogspot.in/)

*/*!
 * Masonry PACKAGED v3.1.3
 * Cascading grid layout library
 * http://masonry.desandro.com
 * MIT License
 * by David DeSandro
 */*

But when i load the page for the first time ,the grid layout get disrupted with image stacking unorderly on each other.Refer to the image below 
[image]

**But the sites works fine when i just reload it once again.What am i doing wrong how to solve this issue.Any help appreciated..**

Comment: post some code respective your issue instead of images, its good to post the look of the issue, but you have to post code for people here to help you.

Comment: works fine on my chrome